# Search OSGI services by properties

Tags: java, osgi

How can I distinguish between published OSGI services implementing same interface by their properties?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming that you want to retrieve registered services based on certain values for properties, you need to use a **filter** (which is based on the [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP) syntax).

For example:

```
int myport = 5000;
String filter = "&(objectClass=" + MyInterface.class.getName() 
                + ")(port=" + myport + ")";
ServiceReference[] serviceReferences = bundleContext.getServiceReferences(null,filter);
```

where you want to look for services both implementing `MyInterface` and having a value of the `port` property equal to `myport`.

[Here](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getServiceReferences%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is the relevant javadoc for getting the references.

**Remark 1:**

The above example and javadoc refer to the Release 4.2. If you are not restricted to a J2SE 1.4 runtime, I suggest you to have a look at the Release 4.3 [syntax](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getServiceReferences%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29), where you can use generics.

**Remark 2: (courtesy of Ray)**

You can also pre-check the correctness of your filter by instead creating a [Filter](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/Filter.html) object from a `filterStr` string:

```
Filter filter = bundleContext.createFilter(filterStr);
```

which also allows you to match the filter with other criteria. You still pass `filterStr` to get the references, since there is no overloading that accounts for a `Filter` argument. Please be aware, however, that in this way you will check the correctness twice: both `getServiceReferences` and `createFilter` throw `InvalidSyntaxException` on parsing the filter. Certainly not a show-stopper inefficiency, I guess, but it is worth mentioning.

Comment: I would just add that it would be good to validate the filter syntax using Filter filter = bundleContext.createFilter(filterStr); first, just for early sanity checking, especially the more dynamic your filter creation gets.

Comment: @Ray: a good remark to make. It is unfortunate that OSGi does not force (or even allow) to pass Filter as an argument, though.

Comment: @LucaGeretti is there any more smart way to find declarative OSGI services?

Comment: @user1474038, if you use declarative services, yes. Refer to Neil's answer.

Comment: I think the example filer has an invalid syntax, it must be enclosed by parentheses. The reason the Filter is not used as a parameter is that getServiceReference(s) methods are very low level and not used for app development. At that level the filter usually comes from some configuration which is generally a string anyway. As said before, the method throws an exception when the filter is wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Luca's answer above is correct, however it assumes you are using the low level API for accessing services.

If you are using Declarative Services (which I would generally recommend) then the filter can be added to the `target` attribute of the service reference. For example (using the bnd annotations for DS):

```
@Reference(target = "(port=8080)")
public void setHttpService(HttpService http) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I really wish there was a thorough tutorial on using DS (+annotations). Neil, do you know of one (even if it's for purchase)? Assuming 4.2 (4.3 at most).

Comment: @Ray: as far as books go, none treats bnd annotations since they are not on the standard. For DS I would suggest the book "OSGi and Equinox" (R4.2, still no book around for R4.3 except some references in "OSGi in Depth")

Answer (score 2):

In Blueprint you can specify the filter attribute on the reference or reference-list element. For example:

```
<reference id="sampleRef"
        interface="org.sample.MyInterface"
        filter="(port=5000)"/>
```

Comment: which doesn't work, you get

Unsatisfied requirement(s):
---------------------------
   service:(&(service=MyInterface)(port=5000))
      [container-name]

when starting the container (Class and container names changed appropriately). No idea what that error is trying to say.

Sadly we're using the hopelessly documented fuse stuff...