# How to get the instance of an OSGi service in AEM, without using @Reference annotation?

Tags: aem, sling

I have a factory service as-

```
com.adobe.test.MyService
```

And i have configured it with multiple configurations at its properties.
I want to use a particularly configured service instance in any of my class.
I can use annotation like-

```
@Reference("uniqueId=878")
MyService myService
```

But what if i want to use the sling method like-

```
com.adobe.test.MyService myService = sling.getService(com.adobe.test.MyService.class);
```

where and how can i define the unique id for a particular instance of my interest?

Answer (score 3):

Object **sling** is an instance of SlingSriptHelper, which has method [getServices](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/api/scripting/SlingScriptHelper.html#getServices%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) which accepts a String as a second parameter, which stands for filtering.

Example of such filtering you can find [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11151622/1675951). Full specification of filter syntax you can find in OSGi specification.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
static <T> T getService(Class<T> serviceClass) {
    BundleContext bContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(serviceClass).getBundleContext();
    ServiceReference sr = bContext.getServiceReference(serviceClass.getName());
        return serviceClass.cast(bContext.getService(sr));
}
```

Then you can call the service

```
MyService ms = getService(MyService.class);
```

Comment: The code you wrote, basically, has no difference from code wrote by @theanubhava.